# Level 3 subgrade resilient modulus

Tags: pavement

Are the typical values provided in Pavement ME for Level 3 subgrade resilient modulus based on material compacted according to AASHTO T 180? I know it says they are in the note to Table 10-10. We run into a problem with this because our unbound aggregate layers are compacted according to T 180, but subgrade is compacted to T 99.

Comment: If it says that they meet AASHO T 180, then you don't want it so as it would be convenient?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the results from T 99 as long as you make sure that the resilient modulus entered for the subgrade layer is representative of the moisture content and density conditions. For instance, if you enter the optimum moisture content and maximum dry density, you should use a resilient modulus for those conditions. If you use in-situ moisture content and density, your resilient modulus should also be representative of in-situ conditions.